# Need help automate iPhone keyboard input throught javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone

I am trying to automate iPHone UI testing throught JavaScript.

I am in a compose mail page and I need to enter email-id in the TO,CC & BCC fields. I have the focus in TO field and keyboard is displayed. To field is UIATextField, however the usual way of entering data into textfield is not entering the data.

I used the following code

```
var app = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp(); 
app.keyboard().elements()["go"].tap();
```

But did no good for me :(

I want to input the email address(abc@xyz.com) through the displayed keyboard.

Please help me with a code snippet. Also please let me know  how to change the focus from "TO" field to "CC" which are one below the other.

The `Header`, `Body` buttons on the page are a `segmentedControls`. I am not able to tap them using the code snippet.

```
var app = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp();
app.segmentedControls()[0].buttons()["Body"].tap();
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance
Kiran

Comment: Please, fix the tags. visual-c++ is for Microsoft compiler used for developing on Windows, not iPhone. You want the iphone tag.

Comment: sorry for the wrong tagging. I dint realise when was it tagged :)

Comment: What's wrong with having the values hard coded into the page and then changing it back when you ship?

Comment: I am not even able to insert a hardcoded value to that field. The "TO", "CC" fields are detected as UIATextFields when I display the logElementTree(). But still textFields()["TO"].setValue("abc@xyz.com") is not entering the data to the to field. and no exception is displayed either.

Comment: Hi guys.. i'm able to achieve the key tapping programmatically, hence the TO field is populated with the desired email address.

Comment: But I have a problem in handling the pop which appears after I click on the send button for the email. I click on the Send button on the navigation bar with the following code <br>app.navigationBar().buttons["Send']; <br>I get a pop with two button cancel and send. I am unable to click on the "Send" button on the pop as the default is set to Cancel and any operation on the pop up leads to "Cancel" button being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this a little better and with some reusability. Try defining a method like this:

```
function typeCharacters(inputString) {
    for(var i in inputString) {
        target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString(inputString[i]);
    }
    target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("\n");
}
```

A quick test of this might look like this:

```
var timestamp = new Date().toString();
typeCharacters(timestamp);
```

Then you sit back and enjoy watching the keyboard type out a nice date for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to automate the keyboard tapping

This is the code snippet which worked for me

```
//Get the keyboard handle
var keyBoard=app.keyboard();

//Get the handle for keys
var keys = keyBoard.keys();

//Get the handle for buttons on the keyboard (Space, Enter, Shift etc)
var keyButtons = keyBoard.buttons();


//To type "hi"
//type "h"
keys.firstWithName("h").tap();

//insert a delay for the tap() action to be completed
target.delay(0.5);


keys.firstWithName("i").tap();

target.delay(0.5);
```